# What does _T stands for in a CString

Tags: c++, unicode, cstring

What does the "T" represents in a string. For example _T("Hello").I have seen this in projects where unicode support is needed.What it actually tells the processor

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`_T` stands for “text”. It will turn your literal into a Unicode wide character literal if and only if you are compiling your sources with Unicode support. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx.

Comment: Technically, `_T()` is only used with the C runtime library, for use with the `_TCHAR` data type. The Win32 equivalent is the `TEXT()` macro for use with the `TCHAR` data type. Both map to `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` are defined during compiling, respectively. Both are usually defined/undefined together, so many people tend to interchange them and things usually work. But they are *logically* separate and *should* be treated accordingly. Use `_TCHAR` and `_T()` with C functions. Use `TCHAR` and `TEXT()` with the Win32 API.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Now here's the tricky question: Which one to use with MFC/ATL's `CString` type? `CString` is implemented both in terms of the CRT as well as the Windows API.

Comment: Per the documentation: "***CString is based on the `TCHAR` data type**.*", so use `TEXT()`.

Answer (score 18):

It's actually used for projects where Unicode **and** ANSI support is required. It tells the compiler to compile the string literal as either Unicode or ANSI depending on the value of a precompiler define.

Why you would want to do this is another matter. If you want to support Unicode by itself then just write Unicode, in this case `L"Hello"`. The `_T()` macro was added when you needed to support Windows NT and later (which support Unicode) and Windows 9x/ME (which do not). These days any code using these macros is obsolete, since all modern Windows versions are Unicode-based.

Answer (score 15):

From MSDN:

> Use the `_T` macro to code literal strings generically, so they compile as Unicode strings under Unicode or as ANSI strings (including MBCS) without Unicode

Answer (score 5):

It stands for TEXT. You can peek the definition when using IDE tools:

```
#define _TEXT(x)    __T(x)
```

But I would like to memorize it as "Transformable", or "swi-T-ch":

```
L"Hello"  //change "Hello" string into UNICODE mode, in any case;

_T("Hello") //if defined UNICODE, change "Hello" into UNICODE; otherwise, keep it in ANSI.
```